# Breaststroke swimming - is it moderate or vigorous?

Tags: exercise, cardio, training

physical activity guidelines recommend

> At least 150 minutes a week of moderate intensity activity such as
> brisk walking

But it also says I can do *for 75 minutes vigorous level activity.*

My main question is: **is swimming using Breaststroke style considered vigorous level?** if no which style is?

And also can I spread it out like do it every second day?

Answer (score 4):

> is swimming using Breaststroke style considered vigorous level?

This depends on how hard you're doing it. It would be considered vigorous if, when you reach the end of the pool and stop, you are breathing so hard that if you tried to speak you'd struggle to get a sentence out without having to stop to breathe.

This would probably be difficult to reach in breaststroke as it uses fewer muscles and gives you less time to breathe compared to the front crawl.

> And also can I spread it out like do it every second day?

Yes. World Health Organisation physical activity guidelines do not specify the number of days per week on which aerobic exercise should be performed, only how much is done in total per week.

Comment: I would add a caveat - Breastroke is more of a full body activity than freestyle, and if you are not trained in it, it can be quite strenuous. It can be anything from a very relaxing idly moving to very hard depending on effort and training level.